# When signing up a subclass of ParseUser, signUpInBackground never completes

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, parse-server

I've got the following code:

```
ParseUser user = (ParseUser) ParseUser.create("_User");

// Set standard fields
user.setUsername(username);
user.setPassword(password);
user.setEmail(email);

// Set additional custom fields
user.put("firstName", fname);
user.put("lastName", lname);

user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            loadingFinish();
            signupSuccess();
        } else {
            loadingFinish();
            debugLog(getString(R.string.com_parse_ui_login_warning_parse_signup_failed) +
                e.toString());
            switch (e.getCode()) {
                case ParseException.INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS:
                    .... // error cases handled here
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Notes:

- I'm instantiating the new ParseUser using `ParseUser.create("_User")`.
  I can't call `new ParseUser()` because I have a subclass of ParseUser registered, so calling `new ParseUser()` throws an exception.
- I have a subclass of ParseUser registered. I can't instantiate my ParseUser
  subclass from this code, because it's in a different package.

## The problem:

#### The `SignUpCallback`'s `done()` method **is never called for successful signups**.

- It's only called if there's a `ParseException`. For successful signups, it's not as if the callback receives a null `ParseException`. It *never even gets called*, and the app sits there uselessly, waiting.
- Debugging breakpoints set in the `done()` method never get tripped for successful signups.
- The new user does get saved to Parse correctly.

What can I do? Am I doing something incorrectly? Is there a different workaround for signing up users while having a ParseUser subclass registered?

---

### Update:

I moved the code to the same package as my ParseUser subclass, so I could instantiate my subclass and run `signup` on that. No luck, same result: a successful signup means the `done()` callback is never called.